# Get Date value from object property - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i get only the Date without the string value from below object?

```
0: {2020-09-02: "string_1", 2020-09-03: "string_2"}
1: {2020-09-01: "string_1", 2020-09-05: "string_2"}
```

My objective is to get the Date only and group them into one array.

Expected result: `[2020-09-02, 2020-09-03, 2020-09-01, 2020-09-05]`

What I tried so far is using *Object.getOwnPropertyNames*:

`console.log('property name: ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(getDateProperties)) // return ["0","1"]`

Is this something possible to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried with Object.keys(getDateProperties)

Comment: yes did tried it before but result is similar which return, ["0", "1"] @Asutosh

Comment: are you sure your data is an Object and not an Array of objects?

Comment: You need to access inner object keys

Comment: @1aliff I have posted the answer using Object.keys. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduce and Object keys to get the dates from the object

```js
const list = [{
    "2020-09-02": "string_1",
    "2020-09-03": "string_2"
  },
  {
    "2020-09-01": "string_1",
    "2020-09-05": "string_2"
  }
]
const result = list.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(x)
  acc = [...acc, ...keys]
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let obj = {
0: {"2020-09-02": "string_1", "2020-09-03": "string_2"},
1: {"2020-09-01": "string_1", "2020-09-05": "string_2"}
}
let arr = [];
for(var key in obj){
    for(var subkey in obj[key]){
        arr.push(subkey);
    }
}
console.log('property name: ', arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    "2020-09-02": "string_1",
    "2020-09-03": "string_2"
  },
  1: {
    "2020-09-01": "string_1",
    "2020-09-05": "string_2"
  }
}
const resultArray = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => Object.keys(obj[k]).forEach((dateArg) => resultArray.push(dateArg)));
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick one-liner

```js
let obj = {
    0: {"2020-09-02": "string_1", "2020-09-03": "string_2"},
    1: {"2020-09-01": "string_1", "2020-09-05": "string_2"}
}

let output = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => [...acc, ...Object.keys(obj[key])], [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `Object.keys` should simplify

```js
const list = [
  {
    "2020-09-02": "string_1",
    "2020-09-03": "string_2",
  },
  {
    "2020-09-01": "string_1",
    "2020-09-05": "string_2",
  },
];

const res = list.flatMap(Object.keys);

console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, if the input data is object.

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    "2020-09-02": "string_1",
    "2020-09-03": "string_2"
  },
  1: {
    "2020-09-01": "string_1",
    "2020-09-05": "string_2"
  }
}

const res = Object.values(obj).flatMap(Object.keys);

console.log(res)
```